# How can I fully duplicate an Excel sheet in another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have workbook A, which has 20 sheets in it, that I work out of consistently.  There are 3 sheets out of this workbook that I would like to put into a new workbook, and put it in the public folder of my dropbox so i can share it with my partners.  These sheets are active, meaning I am editing the content and formating as data etc. is being entered and arguably consumed.

I know how to have data transfer over automatically, I know you can copy paste, etc.  I also know what happens when you just use formulas to transfer data, it doesn't transfer formating.

Is there a way to make Sheet A in Workbook A identical including data and formating to Sheet A in Workbook B.

I'ts like I want to right click on the sheet tab and be able to make it equal to another sheet in another workbook..equal in all ways.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which version you are using, so this is a rather generic answer.

To copy the sheet "AS IS", right click on the tab you want to copy and select `Move or copy...`. In the dialog that appears, select `(new book)` and check `Create a copy`. This should copy the sheet as it is with data and formatting into a new workbook.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I often just save the whole workbook under a new name and then delete the sheets I don't need. This should work for any version or other software such as OpenOffice. Also useful if you use the same layout from one year for the next - just keep all the sheets.